# Simple "arrow-throwing" console game

Tags: c#, game, console

I'm trying to make a simple console application game.  The code is a bit messy and I hope anyone can point out anything wrong.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace CalculatePoints
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Game game = new Game();
        game.PlayGame();
    }
}

class Game
{
    private List<Player> player = new List<Player>();

    public void AddPlayer(string name)
    {
        Player person = new Player(name);
        player.Add(person);
    }

    public void PlayGame()
    {
        Console.Write("enter amount of player: ");
        int playerAmount = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        for (int i = 0; i < playerAmount; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("enter player name: ");
            string playerName = Console.ReadLine();
            AddPlayer(playerName);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("game start");
        foreach (Player name in player)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(name + " turn ");

            Console.WriteLine("enter score 1:");
            int score1 = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("enter score 2:");
            int score2 = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("enter score 3:");
            int score3 = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Throw result = new Throw(score1, score2, score3);
            Console.WriteLine(result.GetScore());
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

class Player
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Throw> throwList = new List<Throw>();

    public Player(string name = "")
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}

class Throw
{
    private int throwOne;
    private int throwTwo;
    private int throwThree;

    public Throw(int throwOne = 0, int throwTwo = 0, int throwThree = 0)
    {
        this.throwOne = throwOne;
        this.throwTwo = throwTwo;
        this.throwThree = throwThree;
    }

    public int GetScore()
    {
        return throwOne + throwTwo + throwThree;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Your total score is {0}", GetScore());
    }
}
}
```

Comment: We cannot help with adding additional implementation.  It must be complete and working.

Comment: @Jamal hey, i have edited the code to full, please take a look.

Comment: If it still doesn't do the things you were asking us to implement, you can remove those requests and the question can be reopened.  *That* aspect can still be asked on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Jamal ok, i think i understand now. I have removed the requests for implement and only for a better code organization.

Comment: Are the `Player` methods incomplete?  They don't seem to be doing anything useful.

Comment: No, i haven't got an idea for `CalculatePoints` and `AddArrows`, right now the `Player` simply returns the user's input for name.

Comment: If the game doesn't run entirely, then this is still incomplete.  I'm not too familiar with C#, so I can't quite test this well enough.

Comment: I have removed the `CalculatePoints` and `AddArrows` methods, i'm not focusing them at the moment. It basically lets you enter the player amount and their names, then different points.

Comment: To me this looks like it's reviewable in the state it's in currently. But I would suggest that maybe you'd get a *better* review if you waited until it was completely finished and posted that instead. As it is, we can probably give you pointers in the right direction, but not much in the way of concrete examples like "look how much better it would be to do X rather than Y"

Comment: alright, gonna work on it and come back again.

Answer (score 10):

I like that your `Program` class is kept to a minimum. That's a very good start.

The `player` field in the `Game` class has a bad/misleading name: it's not *one* player, it's a *list of players*. `players` would be better. Also I'd make that field `readonly` to make it clear that the *reference* of that list cannot be tampered with. I'd also consider passing that list of players through the constructor as an argument... but that would break your code, because `PlayGame` is doing too many things.

The first part of `PlayGame` should be extracted out of the class: it's more of a *GetGamePlayers* method than a part of the actual game code.

The name `Throw`, throws me off: `throw` is a keyword reserved for *throwing* exceptions; considering the nature and purpose of the class, perhaps `PlayerTurn` would be a better choice.

---

The `Player` class is doing something terribly wrong: it's exposing a public field! The `throwList` can be reassigned and messed with from the outside, which completely ruins *encapsulation*. Consider exposing it with an `IEnumerable<T>` *property getter* instead.

Similarly, the `Name` setter should be `private`.

Also, `playerAmount` is really a `playerCount` - "amount" is typically better suited for quantities of something, money in particular comes to mind.

---

For flexibility, you shouldn't hard-code the 3 throws in your `Throw` (/`PlayerTurn`) class: should the rules change and players are now allowed a 4th dart, or if a player's turn can end with only one or two darts thrown, the hard-coded `throwOne`, `throwTwo` and `throwThree` become a problem. Granted, the optional parameters help a bit, but why store values that you don't need? I'd have gone with a `List` here too.

Comment: You could also mention that `playerAmount` should be renamed to `playerNumber` (same thing with the input prompt).  It's awkward to say "amount" in this context.

Comment: @Jamal indeed! Phone post, will edit ;)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm starting over and try rewriting them correctly.

Answer (score 4):

I have some minor points to add to everyone's answers.

Your `Throw` class fields should be prefixed by `_` <del>as it is the C# coding convention</del> (check comments below!), doing this would also let you not use `this` in your constructor

```
private int _throwOne;
private int _throwTwo;
private int _throwThree;

public Throw(int throwOne = 0, int throwTwo = 0, int throwThree = 0)
{
    _throwOne = throwOne;
    _throwTwo = throwTwo;
    _throwThree = throwThree;
}
```

In your `Player` class you expose a public field, which is a `List`, you shouldn't do that. Instead you should expose a read-only property interface (Like `ICollection<>` or `IEnumerable<>`) and initialize this property in your constructor.

```
public ICollection<Throw> ThrowList {get;private set;}

public Player(string name = "")
{
    Name = name;
    ThrowList = new List<Throw>();
}
```

Finally, your application will crash if the user enters anything that isn't an `Int32` in the prompts for the scores or the number of players. You should validate your input and maybe re-ask the user for the score/number of players until it is a valid input.

Comment: Underscore is not an official coding convention in C#. It is highly debatable, with at most a 50% usage rate. I will now go about proving this to be true by saying not to use it.

Comment: I might be mistaken, I learned it that way and always thought it was a standard

Comment: Don't worry, it's common enough. Some official .NET libraries were written that way, and some weren't. If you use Resharper (and probably other, similar tools), you can make color do the job of an underscore as well.

Answer (score 1):

I have few bits of code:

Pass the collection together, rather than individually, as you might need to change it.

As you are reading from `Console.ReadLine`, create a method that takes the value according to the type (up to your judgement).

A few variable are redundant, so you can remove them.

```
public class Game
{
    private readonly List<Player> _player = new List<Player>();

    private T GetConsoleValue<T>()
    {
        var value = Console.ReadLine();
        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }

    public void AddPlayer(string name)
    {
        Player person = new Player(name);
        _player.Add(person);
    }

    public void PlayGame()
    {
        Console.Write("enter number of player: ");
        var playersCount = GetConsoleValue<int>();

        for (var count = 0; count < playersCount; count++)
        {
            Console.Write("enter player name: ");
            string playerName = Console.ReadLine();
            AddPlayer(playerName);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("game start");
        foreach (var name in _player)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(name + " turn ");

            Console.WriteLine("enter score 1:");
            var score1 = GetConsoleValue<int>(); 

            Console.WriteLine("enter score 2:");
            var score2 = GetConsoleValue<int>();

            Console.WriteLine("enter score 3:");
            var score3 =  GetConsoleValue<int>();

            var result = new Throw(new List<int>
            {
                score1,
                score2,
                score3
            });
            Console.WriteLine(result.GetScore());
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class Player
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Player(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}

public class Throw
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<int> _throwScores;

    public Throw(IEnumerable<int> throwScores)
    {
        _throwScores = throwScores;
    }

    public int GetScore()
    {
        return _throwScores.Sum();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Your total score is {0}", GetScore());
    }
}
```